# About divisibility of certain sums

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We have the following theorem;

**Theorem**: If $a$ divide $b_1$,$a$ divide $b_2$,...,$a$ divide $b_{n}$, then for any integers $c_1, c_2,\ldots, c_{n}$, $a$ divide $X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^n b_{i}c_{i}$.

My question is **about the existence an inverse or a special inverse of this result**, i.e. a result of the form:

If $a$ divide $X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^n b_{i}c_{i}$ then $a$ divide $b_1$,$a$ divide $b_2$,...,$a$ divide $b_{n}$ for any (or some) integers $c_2, c_2,\ldots,c_{n}$.

I cant find a similar result in the net.

Comment: Interesting. I created  a similar statement yesterday. If $p$ is a prime number such dat $p\mid \sum \limits_{i=1}^{r} (n_i)^2$ (with $n_i$ integers) then $p$ divides each $n_i$.

Comment: @Maman, I don't understand:  If, for example, $n_1=n_2=1$, then $2\mid\sum_{i=1}^2(n_i)^2$, but $2$ does *not* divide each $n_i$.

Comment: @Maman: Can you give a proof here for your statement.

Comment: His statement is not true, take for example $n_1=3$ and $n_2=7$.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: Merci Antoine

Comment: @E.J I wanted to generalize the statement of Toan

Comment: @BarryCipra I just used the fact that if there is an $i$ such dat $p$ does not divide $n_i$ then it cannot divide the sum of squares. But as I see there are lots of counter-examples

Comment: @Maman $n_1=3$ and $n_2=7$ and $n_3=5$ serves as a counterexample for $(n_1)^2 + (n_2)^2 + (n_3)^2$.

Comment: And $n_1=n_2=3$ and $n_3=n_4=5$ for sum of four squares.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin 
But if we want to use contrapositive with $p=5$
 we will have the fact dat : $a=5k$
 and $b=5q+r$
 with $0<|r|<5$
. Then $a^2+b^2=5L+r^2$
 and moreover $5$
 cannot divide $r^2$
. So $5$
 cannot divide $a^2+b^2$
. So it's strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be hard to find solution of that problem without some special constraints, because, we can have that $a$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^n c_ib_i$ but that $a$ divides as many as we want numbers in the set $\{b_1,...b_n\}$.

To see that suppose that we have $\sum_{i=1}^n c_ib_i=da$ for some integer $d$.

Then, if numbers from the set $\{b_{\sigma(i)},...,b_{\sigma(k)}\}$ (this set can be empty) are divisible by $a$ and numbers from the set $\{b_1,...b_n\} \setminus \{b_{\sigma(i)},...,b_{\sigma(k)}\}=\{h_1,...h_l\}$ are not divisible by $a$ then number $\sum_{j=1}^k c_{\gamma(j)} b_{\sigma(j)}$ is divisible by $a$ but the number $\sum_{w=1}^l c_w h_w$ does not need to be divisible by $a$ and there will be solution of $\sum_{w=1}^l c_w h_w=ga$ if and only if $\gcd(c_1,...c_w)$ divides $ga$ so there can be a solution even if none of $\{h_1,...h_l\}$ is divisible by $a$.

To observe this try with some small examples made by you and look on the internet about linear diophantine equations.

Answer (score 2):

I found one, borrowing idea of sum of square from Maman's comment.

> If $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ is a prime and $p \mid a^2+b^2$ then $p\mid a,p \mid b$.

Comment: Take $p=5$ we have the solution $a\equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $b\equiv 0 \pmod 5$. But also $a\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5}$ and $b\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$

Comment: I wrote $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ so $p$ can't be $5$.

Comment: Indeed that's why I precised dat the other case was impossible ;)

Comment: But if we want to use contrapositive with $p=5$ we will have the fact dat : $a=5k$ and $b=5q+r$ with $0<\vert r\vert < 5$. Then $a^2+b^2=5L+r^2$ and moreover $5$ cannot divide $r^2$. So $5$ cannot divide $a^2+b^2$. So it's strange.

Comment: Do you see the mistake ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are writing in the comment. But the property can only work with primes $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: If $5$ divides $a^2+b^2$ then $5$ divides $a$ and $b$ by contrapositive.

Comment: It's not true, because $5=1^2+2^2$.

Comment: I know but if you look at the contrapositive it's strange :)